# Jquery simple modal close window and update parent

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I want to execute some code inside a modal window that validates the data entered, if the data is saved successfully, I want to automatically close the modal window and refresh the parent window.

I've tried to call the modal close function, but no results.

```
<script>jQuery(function() {jQuery.modal.close();});</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this - in your main js:

```
// Open modal
$(foo).dialog(); 

// Listen for a trigger and close dialogue
$(foo).live('data_saved',function(){
    $(this).dialog('close'); // close modal
}
```

In your modal js:

```
// Inside modal, save your data - execute a trigger 
..whatever.trigger('data_saved');
```